# AudioUnit render callback called on iPhone simulator, but not on phone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have a fairly straightforward setup in which a RemoteIO unit is taking input, doing a bit of processing, sending it out the output, and writing the output to a file.  Right now, I'm just generating test signals inside of my RemoteIO render callback, so I don't really care about anything coming from the 'actual' input.  My render callback is called and works a treat in the simulator, but is never called at all when run on the phone.  Any ideas where I should start looking?  Am happy to post code--just not sure what everyone would like to see...

Comment: Can you show code of setting up the audio unit please? Also are there any errors logged when you open the unit? This might be because the format you have asked for is valid on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: Now that @mattjgalloway says it, I also remember that some units support different formats on simulator and device. So it's crucial that you evaluate and log all errors from CoreAudio methods to find this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I knew that things had worked in the past, so I started digging through the repo.  Foolishly, I had changed the `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory` of my `AudioSession` from `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` to `kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio` and forgotten to change it back.  Hope this helps someone else avoid the same stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Just an hour ago I was solving the same. The problem was that I had defined AudioUnit type variable in the header file, so after I used AudioComponentInstance instead of AudioUnit it started to work on my devices as well.
So possibly could be this.